# biblatex \printbibliography missing $

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm using biblatex with biber as backend. Bibliography compiling is perfect, but right now I'm having a problem in printing the bibliography: it seems some character in the bibliography triggers a math environment (something like that) which breaks pdf compiling via Texmaker. Funny thing is I can "ignore" this issue while running pdflatex via comman line, no idea why.
My question is: how can I debug this issue in .bbl file? Or how can I ignore it outright. I'm working on a thesis project and I'd like not to end up with some last second complicated issue. 
Thanks in advance

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03BC}{\mu}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03BA}{\kappa}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2009}{ }

\usepackage{mdframed}

\title{COPD and Chronic HIV Pulmonary Disease}
\author{Simone Neri}
\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{../bibtex/Letteratura.bib}
\addbibresource{../bibtex/HIVCOPD_comorbid.bib}
\addbibresource{../bibtex/litreview.bib}
\begin{document}
blablabla \cite{x} \cite{y}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and here's the log file

```
-- In this line something weird happens but everything goes fine
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+cmr on input line 32.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd
File: omscmr.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OMS/cmr/m/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' tried instead on input line 32.
[...] 
    --here real problems start
    [5] [6]
    ! Missing $ inserted.
    <inserted text> 
                    $
    l.131 \end
              {document}
    I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
    you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

    LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
    (Font)              <7> on input line 130.
    LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
    (Font)              <5> on input line 130.
    ! Missing $ inserted.
    <inserted text> 
                    $
l.131 \end
          {document}
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.


Overfull \hbox (78.91812pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 131--131
\OML/cmm/m/it/10 asubstudyoftheINSIGHTStrategicTimingofAntiRetroviralTreatment\
OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (\OML/cmm/m/it/10 START\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 )\OML/cmm/m/it/10 trial:$
\T1/cmr/m/n/10 ^^T.
 []

[7]
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.131 \end
          {document}
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.131 \end
          {document}
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.


Overfull \hbox (19.52454pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 131--131
\T1/cmr/m/n/10 flam-ma-to-ry Cy-to-ki-nes by Hu-man Den-dri-tic Cells and Mo-no
-cy-tes/Macrophages
 []

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.131 \end
          {document}
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.131 \end
          {document}
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.


Overfull \hbox (79.47566pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 131--131
[]\T1/cmr/m/n/10 Arvind Pan-day et al. ^^S  Trans-crip-tion Fac-tor NF-$\OML/cm
m/m/it/10 ^^TB \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 : \OML/cmm/m/it/10 AnUpdateonInterventionStrateg
ies:$\T1/cmr/m/n/10 ^^T.
 []
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: Seems an bib entry causes the problem. Can you check the log file and add the first wrong bib entry to your question please?

Comment: Add `\usepackage{xcolor}` and `\everymath{\color{red}}` to your document. This should give an indication where TeX starts math mode.

Comment: You probably have one or more `$`, `_`, or `^` characters in some of your bib entries. Please post, e.g., the entry authored by Panday et al.

Comment: This error comes when you use a + sign or anything math related. You have to wrap that inside the `$ $` tags  in your bib file to print it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok now this is awkward but I found the solution myself. Problem was the

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03BC}{\mu}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03BA}{\kappa}
```

I used to read greek mu and kappa letters in scientific paper headings, because those were automatically related to a math environment.

Here's the solution with textgreek package

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03BC}{\textmugreek}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03BA}{\textkappa}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2009}{ }
```

so that no mathematical environment is called